# How can I modify dynamically added html with jQuery.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax call in jQuery which returns and inserts some HTML in my site. In the same call, in the success callback, I want to "do stuff" with the html that is returned.

Some code (simplified):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "some_url.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: some_data,
    success: function(response){

        myAsyncAjaxInsertHtmlFunction(response); // 1. This function is an ajaxcall which inserts HTML dynamically

        $(newlyAddedSelector + ' input').each(function(){ // 2. Here I want to iterate over those dynamically added html elements
            doStuffWithNewlyAddedHtml(this.value);

        });
    }
});
```

The problem is that the dynamically added html isn't loaded yet when the code execution reaches point 2. I know async: false exists but that's not the route I want to take.

How should you generally handle this type of situation, which I can imagine is pretty common?

Comment: `The problem is that the dynamically added html isn't loaded yet when the code execution reaches point 2.` It should be. Can you include the code of `myInsertHtmlFunction` in your question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and also more readable if you place the second block of code within the function that adds the elements?

Comment: myInsertHtmlFunction() returns something? Why not wrap response inside a jquery object and then use classic jquery methods instead?

Comment: I've edited my post. I wasn't clear enought. The myInsertHtmlFunction is also an asynchronous ajax function.

Comment: ok, now `myInsertHtmlFunction` became `myAsyncAjaxInsertHtmlFunction()` so i guess you should return promise interface from `myAsyncAjaxInsertHtmlFunction()` but still you didn't have posted this relevant part of code... And why you are doing two ajax requests is still a mystery

Comment: @A.Wolff : Why I have two ajax requests is because the myAsyncAjaxInsertHtmlFunction() is a general function for loading html templates in my work environment. And my ajax request (the one in my post) is me trying to modify the html which is loaded.

Comment: @Weblurk so returns promise from this async method and use relevant method as `.done()`.

Comment: @A.Wolff Still the same problem. Setting breakpoints in firebug and when the code reached the $.when/done part, the html is still not loaded.

Comment: @Weblurk unfortunately my crystal ball is broken, i cannot see the code you are using. Next time, just think about posting relevant code, thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  fct().done() to wait until the ajax has been executed before you go to your second process

```
function ajax1() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl",
        ...
    });
}


ajax1().done(function(){
        // the code here will be executed when ajax requests resolve.
    });
```

Edited

Comment: This solution looked the most promising but the same problem here. When the code is inside the when/done function the html from ajax1() still hasn't loaded.

Comment: @Weblurk this is wrong syntax to use $.when. You should just use: `ajax1().done(function(){
        // the code here will be executed when ajax requests resolve.
    });`  No need to use $.when here

Comment: try that $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  // the code here will be executed when ajax requests resolve.
});

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes I tried both with $.when and without. No difference at all. The HTML still hasn't loaded, even though the doStuffWithNewlyAddedHtml() function is inside the done() block.

Comment: @Weblurk like i said, without seeing what you are doing (obviously something wrong) how could you expect to someone can help you more??? 35min ago, first comment asking you to post relevant code but still not... That's ok, GL!

Comment: @A. Wolff I have just read some documentation and I agree with you regarding $.when

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried showing as much as necessary without filling up two screens full of code. Also, I thought this problem would be more common. But thank you for your time.

Comment: @Weblurk have you tried to use the ajaxComplete(function() { // the code here will be executed when ajax requests resolve. }) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var insered = false;
 $.ajax({
    url: "some_url.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: some_data,
    success: function(response){

        myInsertHtmlFunction(response); // 1. This function inserts HTML dynamically
        insered = true;

        },
    complete: function(){
        if( insered == true ) {
              $(newlyAddedSelector + ' input').each(function(){ // 2. Here I want to iterate over those dynamically added html elements
                 doStuffWithNewlyAddedHtml(this.value);
             });
        }
    }
});
```

You can insert your html in success in do your final stuff in complete method.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your `myInsertHtmlFunction` function does something `async`, your code should work, because adding&removing HTML elements always sync.

But if your application logic, also modifies HTML, depending on load status of some newly added elements, such as, adding a div if a newly added image finishes loading, then your code would fail.

It all depends on `myInsertHtmlFunction` function.

Comment: Good point. I have edited my text. The myInsertHtmlFunction IS an ajax call which insert html elements. So it's not possible to wait for those elements to finish loading before running my code somehow?

Comment: Yes there is two ways, 1. see яша's answer which utilizes promises, 2. just pass a callback to your myInsertHtmlFunction, and put your HTML modifying code inside that callback function, on myInsertHtmlFunction catch incoming callback function as a parameters, and only execute it after ajax call inside myInsertHtmlFunction finishes.